# Attempting to create dynamic button class in Kivy in Python but getting invalid property name

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying this out and I'm wondering why I'm not quite getting it. I tried adding the code, but am getting:

> Invalid property name on the line:
>
> ```
>  <MyButton@Button>:
> ```

Dynamic class declaration:

```
<MyButton@Button>:
     text: 'My Button!'
      # .. other Button properties
```

So the entire bit of code is:

```
 <GridLayout>
     cols: 4
     row_default_height: 100

 <MyButton@Button>:
     text: 'My Button!'
     # .. other Button properties

MyButton:
    # properties I might want to set that aren't specified in dynamic class
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your code I see these declarations:

- `' <GridLayout>'`
- `' <MyButton@Button>:'`

If it's not just a formatting issue here on SO (Ctrl+K for propper formatting), then this will raise an error, because widget/rule declarations are only at the first level (*read:* without any characters before `<`, `' '` is a character too), which means the parser treats the declaration as a property probably because it contains `:` character or maybe just because it's not at first level, which would mean that such string is either a property or a widget. (or a continuation of the previous line)